# IntelliJ IDEA creating an MSI-installer for a JavaFX application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, windows-installer

I'm trying to create an MSI-installer for my JavaFX application. This is briefly what I've done so far. I created a new artifact for JavaFX and selected the Native Bundle to be MSI in the Java FX -tab. After that, I built the artifact. When I opened the output -folder, there was no .msi installer. Instead, there were 3 other files (one HTML-, jar-, and jnlp-file). What am I missing here? Where is the MSI-file?

[image: MSI option being selected in project structrure's Artifacts-tab]

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have such a feature. Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html and to https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ . I don't see any mention of the MSI installers there.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Well, at least it is an option when adding a new artifact (I added a picture of it in my question). Anyways, the reason why it didn't work is probably, as mipa answered, me not having jpackage installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is all part of standard JDK 14. Its called jpackage.
If you need a tutorial to see how it works have a look here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX